# Android: TextToSpeech doesn't work on Android 4.1

Tags: android

Does anybody have idea why the `TextToSpeech` method I have here doesn't work anymore on Android 4.1?

On the `sayIt()` method it always returns `Log.i(TAG, "Failure: TextToSpeech instance tts was not properly initialized");`

```
public class SpeakSuperActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

    private final static String TAG = "TextToSpeech";

    protected static final Locale defaultLocale = Locale.GERMAN;
    private static int TTS_DATA_CHECK = 100;
    protected TextToSpeech tts = null;
    protected boolean ttsIsInit = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Use an Intent and startActivityForResult to check whether TTS data installed on the
        // device. Result returned and acted on in method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) below.

        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, TTS_DATA_CHECK);
    }

    // protected void initTextToSpeech() {
    // Log.d(TAG, "TTS initTextToSpeech() called");
    // Intent intent = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    // startActivityForResult(intent, TTS_DATA_CHECK);
    // }

    protected void onActivityResultOld(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TTS_DATA_CHECK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: TTS_DATA_CHECK fork reached");
            if (resultCode == Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Data installed: Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS fork reached");
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
                // tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new OnInitListener() {
                // public void onInit(int status) {
                // if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                // Log.w(TAG, "TTS onInit() success :)");
                // ttsIsInit = true;
                // if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.UK) >= 0) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "Local UK available");
                // tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                // }
                // if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.GERMAN) >= 0) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "Local German available");
                // tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);
                // }
                // tts.setPitch(0.8f);
                // tts.setSpeechRate(1.1f);
                // speak("Hallo Sprücheklopfer");
                // } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                // Log.w(TAG, "TTS onInit() failed :(");
                // }
                // }
                // });

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "TTS not installed yet, calling intent to install...");
                Intent installVoice = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installVoice);
            }
        }

    }

    // Create the TTS instance if TextToSpeech language data are installed on device. If not
    // installed, attempt to install it on the device.

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TTS_DATA_CHECK) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {

                // Success, so create the TTS instance. But can't use it to speak until
                // the onInit(status) callback defined below runs, indicating initialization.

                Log.i(TAG, "Success, let's talk");
                // XXX: NOTE: it is REALLY important to use new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this) instead of new TextToSpeech(this, this)!
                tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);

                // // Use static Locales method to list available locales on device
                // Locale locales [] = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
                // Log.i(TAG,"Locales Available on Device:");
                // for(int i=0; i<locales.length; i++){
                // String temp = "Locale "+i+": "+locales[i]+" Language="
                // +locales[i].getDisplayLanguage();
                // if(locales[i].getDisplayCountry() != "") {
                // temp += " Country="+locales[i].getDisplayCountry();
                // }
                // Log.i(TAG, temp);
                // }

            } else {
                // missing data, so install it on the device
                Log.i(TAG, "Missing Data; Install it");
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            ttsIsInit = true;

            // Set to a language locale after checking availability
            Log.i(TAG, "defaultLocaleAvailable=" + tts.isLanguageAvailable(defaultLocale));
            tts.setLanguage(defaultLocale);
            // Examples of voice controls. Set to defaults of 1.0.
            tts.setPitch(1.0F);
            tts.setSpeechRate(1.0F);
            // Issue a greeting and instructions in the default language
            // speakGreeting(defaultLocale.getDisplayLanguage());
            // sayIt("Hallo Sprücheklopfer", true);
        } else {
            ttsIsInit = false;
            Log.i(TAG, "Failure: TextToSpeech instance tts was not properly initialized");
        }
    }

    // protected void speak(String text) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "TTS sould say: " + text);
    // if (tts != null && ttsIsInit) {
    // tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    // } else {
    // Log.w(TAG, "TTS not initialised or null");
    // }
    // }

    // Method to speak a string. The boolean flushQ determines whether the text is
    // appended to the queue (if false), or if the queue is flushed first (if true).

    public void sayIt(String text, boolean flushQ) {
        if (tts != null && ttsIsInit) {
            if (flushQ) {
                tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            } else {
                tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Failure: TextToSpeech instance tts was not properly initialized");
        }
    }

    // Release TTS resources when finished

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
            ttsIsInit = false;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onInitOld(int status) {
        Log.i(TAG, "TTS onInit() status :" + status);
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            Log.w(TAG, "TTS onInit() success :)");
            ttsIsInit = true;
            if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.UK) >= 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Local UK available");
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
            if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.GERMAN) >= 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Local German available");
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);
            }
            tts.setPitch(0.8f);
            tts.setSpeechRate(1.1f);
            sayIt("Hallo Sprücheklopfer", true);
        } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Log.w(TAG, "TTS onInit() failed :(");
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "TTS onInit() unknown status :" + status);
        }
    }

}
```